# Experiencing error while running web application based on React Gatsby: Error #98123

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I am developing a webpage using Gatsby.  Whenever I run 'gatsby develop' i get the error message below.

```
ERROR #98123  WEBPACK

Generating development JavaScript bundle failed

Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

File: src\css\index.css

failed Building development bundle - 15.530s
```

This is how the src\css\index.css file looks like:

```
@tailwind base;

@tailwind components;

@tailwind utilities;
```

- I have tried deleting the 'node_modules' folder
- I have tried deleting 'yarn.lock'
- I have tried running 'gatsby clean'
- I have updated 'Node'

Nothing seems to work.  May someone assist me please?